# Intel NUC running Ubuntu 20.04 had its wireless device marked as UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, wireless

I wanted to use the wireless network device that is embedded in this NUC: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/217669/intel-nuc-11-essential-kit-nuc11atkc4/specifications.html

The device is currently running some services and has connectivity to the internet via ethernet.

When I run `lshw -C network`, it looks like the network device is marked as UNCLAIMED

I've extracted most of the information requested in this pastebin: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Ys8dqwFMkk/

I've tried installing `linux-firmware` then rebooting without any results.

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

From your pastebin I can see the wireless adapter in your device is [8086:4df0] which is the Intel AX201.

I see you are running kernel version 5.4.0, which is the GA kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. While the AX201 should be supported in kernel versions 5.2+ and up you might have better luck with a more recent kernel and firmware.

You can try with the latest Ubuntu 20.04 hardware enablement kernel, which is 5.15, by installing the linux-generic-hwe-20.04 package.

e.g.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-20.04 
sudo reboot
```